# Getting value from javascript tags in array form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I created tag using web tutorials.

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/A5TJh/1/

Inside:

```
  for (var i in tags){
    tagString.push(tags[i].value);

  }
```

if I `alert(tags[i])` it alerts correctly.

But when I use `tags` before end of function that it alerts `undefined`.

My purpose is to store all `tags` in an array and push POST this array to `PHP` file. But the issue is I am not able to retrieve tags value in array. As it is already in `tags` array, I thought I could access it directly.

Comment: It's probably a scope kind of problem. Maybe you want to rewrite the fiddle so you have the HTML for the POST too, to see if the problem is there

Comment: In your fiddle, you're alerting tags.value.  If you want to see the contents of the tags array, then use console.log(tags).  You'll see that there is an array of objects created, each object represents a tag in the input field.

Comment: @jme11: can you please tell me how can I access it in seperate function, so that I can post the array values

Answer (score 0):

You need values like 1, 2, 3 or tags names like tag1, tag2, tag3?
Call someMethod with argument like `tagString`

```
instance.tagit({
    tagSource: availableTags,
    tagsChanged: function () {

        //Get the tags            
        var tags = instance.tagit('tags');
        var tagString = [];

        //Pull out only value
        for (var i in tags) {
            tagString.push(tags[i].value);
        }

        someMethod(tagString);

        //Put the tags into the input, joint by a ','
        input.val(tagString.join(','));

        function someMethod(tags) {
            console.log(tags);
            // call POST action
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to just retrieve the values from the DOM, rather than try to store them in an array.  If you store them in array as they are being created, then you have to keep an eye on changes, such as if the user deletes one of the tags.

So I would just retrieve the values when the user performs their submit action.  The values are stored in a hidden unordered list and each has a class of .tagit-choice, so just iterate over the list and retrieve the text values:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/affLX/)**

```
$('.tagit-choice').each(function () {
  alert($(this).contents(':not(a)').text());
});
```

Naturally, you can use the each method to create an array once you're ready to post like this:

```
tagsForPost = [];
$('.tagit-choice').each(function (i) {
     tagObj = {value: i, label: $(this).contents(':not(a)').text()};
     tagsForPost.push(tagObj);
});
console.log(tagsForPost);
```